# How to reduce whitespaces without removing them completely?

Tags: html, twig, whitespace

Often I have template bits looking like

```
<div class="mydiv
   {{ with_icon ? 'with-icon' }}
   {{ full_width ? 'full-width' }}
   {{ is_granted('foo') ? 'bar' }}"
>
```

which generates unwanted spaces

```html
<div class="mydiv
    with-icon
    full-width
    bar"
>
```

and looks in devtools like:
[image]

As you imagine, I'd like it to be:

```html
<div class="mydiv with-icon full-width bar">
```

Using `spaceless` and add a space to each string being not a clean solution, to me.

Is there any straightforward solution for this?

Comment: FWIW, the browser does not care about those spaces, and unless you dig, you'll never seem them either…

Comment: I know but it would make the source a lot more readable, and, for some huge cases, lighter.

Comment: FYI *spaceless* does not work on html (attributes). My suggestion would just to remove the newlines in your template

Comment: @DarkBee it wouldn't be readable. `spaceless` not working on attributes? Strange, I'll give it a try...

Comment: As stated in the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/spaceless.html): "Use the spaceless filter to remove whitespace *between* HTML tags, not whitespace *within* HTML tags or whitespace in plain text:"

Comment: Perhaps you can use a custom buffer strategy - see [here](https://coderwall.com/p/fatjmw/compressing-html-output-with-php)

Comment: does https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#other-operators "whitespace control" answer your question ?

Comment: @Pierre unfortunately not!